# JavaScript error with html form submit

Tags: php, javascript

```
function formv(frm){

    alert(frm.username.value);

    document.myform.submit();
}

<form action="http://localhost/CI/index.php/scontr/logs" method="post" name="myform">
        <fieldset>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>UserID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" value="" /></td>
            </tr>

                            <tr><td>
                            <select name="myselect">
                            <option value="one" >Teacher</option>
                            <option value="two" >Student</option>
                            </select></td>
                            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="submit" onclick="formv(this.form)" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Can anyone tell me why the above form is not being posted in the following address. The alert box is shown,  but then nothing happens. It remains in the same page

Comment: do you get an error in your browser's error console?

Comment: its saying document.myform.submit is not a function

Comment: try using document.forms[0].submit()

Comment: Who downvoted and voted to close, it is a valid question. Sad you do not know the problem that is pretty common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your submit button to something else since `document.myform.submit` now references the button and not the submit action.

change

```
name="submit"
```

to

```
name="btnSubmit"
```